# .Htaccess Sub Domain extensions not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want the following to work:

```
<subdomain>.domain.com
```

to show content from the following directory

```
/sites/<subdomain>
```

and I have to got it to work to show the Index (in HTML or PHP) but if I go on http://.domain.com/test it is mean to display test.html or test.php whichever is present. I am given /sites/index.php is not found.

Here is my .HTAccess

```
Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -Multiviews
IndexIgnore *
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
ServerSignature EMail
SetEnv SERVER_ADMIN admin@domain.com
SetEnv CI_ENV development

<FilesMatch ".(htaccess|ini|phps|log|sh)$">
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|json|xml|tpl)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 400 /views/global/error/400.html
ErrorDocument 401 /views/global/error/401.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/404
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404
ErrorDocument 500 /views/global/error/500.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.json -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.json [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.tpl -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.template [L]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)  %{HTTP_HOST}$1 [C]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.domain\.com(.*) /sites/$1/$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} proc/self/environ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*(.*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]

RewriteRule ^errors(|/)$ / [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^errors/(.*)$ /views/global/errors/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^global/(.*)$ /views/global/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)/forums(|/)(.*)$ /sites/forums/index.php [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)/templates/(.*)$ /views/templates/$3 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)/$ /views/index [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /views/$1/$2/$3_$4_$5 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /views/$3_$4 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)/([^/]+)?$ /views/$3 [L,NC]
```

And the Error log shows the following:

```
[Thu Oct 20 14:33:24.679400 2016] [:error] [pid 8076:tid 1872] [client 141.101.99.135:31179] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/sites/index.php' not found or unable to stat
[Thu Oct 20 14:33:24.682401 2016] [:error] [pid 8076:tid 1872] [client 141.101.99.135:31179] script 'C:/xampp/htdocs/sites/index.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Comment: First glance, there should probably be an `[OR]` at the end of this line : `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d`

Comment: @CD001 thanks, added it!

Comment: I think your other issue is with the RewriteRules like these : `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f` ... you can pass a match from the RewriteCond using `%X` (rather than `$X`) so you might want: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/(.*)\.html -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ %1.html [L]` instead

Comment: @CD001 If I do that then I get an issue saying /views/index is not found (with no .html at the end)

Comment: To be honest - I've not gone through that chunk at the bottom yet - I've not been using any URLs that would trigger it; I have got `example.domain.com/badgers.html` happily redirecting to `domain.com/sites/example/badgers.html` though ...

Comment: @CD001 The issue is I don't want it to redirect, I want it to become the ROOT DIRECTORY of the sub domain, so it should be: `example.domain.com/badgers` would get it from `/sites/example/badgers.html`

Comment: That's still a redirect - albeit one behind the scenes (it displays `example.domain.com/badgers.html` in the address bar)... would be considerably easier to just configure `<VirtualHost>` directories in `httpd-vhosts.conf` but I'm assuming you want this to be dynamic. I can't post what I've got as an answer because it goes into a terminal loop rather than 404-ing at the moment when the file doesn't exist in `/sites/example/` :(

Comment: @CD001 Yeah thats what is happening to me too

Comment: @CD001 and about how it displays .html extension, I really want to get rid of that.